# TypeError: must be real number, not str : Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting this Error: `TypeError: must be real number, not str`. when i printing the request data `lat2`, `lon2` then it's print float types of number. when i running below code then it's throwing me error that, must be realnumber not str type. 
It would be great if anybody could help me out to solve this issues. thank you so much in advance.

```
def distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2): 

    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])     
    # Haversine formula  
    dlon = lon2 - lon1  
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
  
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))  
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers 
    return(c * r) # calculate the result
```

```
class GarageShopDetailAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        lat2 = self.request.GET.get('lat2', None)
        lon2 = self.request.GET.get('lon2', None)

        queryset = ShopOwnerShopDetails.objects.filter(id=query_id)
        serializer = ShopOwnerShopDetailsSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request':request})
        data = serializer.data
        km_difference = []
        for record in data:
            lon1 = record['lon']
            lat1 = record['lat']
            km_differ = distance(lon1, lat1, lon2 , lat2)
            km_difference.append({"km_difference":km_differ})
```

Comment: what happens if you run them through `float`?

Comment: and since you get lat2,lon2 from request.GET, you should check the format `'1.43'.replace('.','',1).isdigit()` or put try-except around it

Comment: Where is the printing happening that you are referring to?

Comment: @PaulH  Issue has been resolved. by converting to `float` value. thanks you very much.